# Installing Craft 3 using MAMP Pro on Windows

Tags: install

I have been trying to install Craft 3 using MAMP Pro on Windows 10 Pro with no luck. I look around but it's mostly installing on a Mac or it is 3 to 4 years old. Does anybody have a step-by-step guide on how to do that? Craft is definitely a different animal installing locally than WordPress.

Comment: Are there any specific issues or error messages that you're running into that you can share? Probably worth linking to the official installation docs (https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/installation.html#web-browser-setup) and install troubleshooting guide (https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/troubleshooting-failed-installation).

Comment: I have tried everything even placed the unzip craft file in mamp htdoc folder. I did the simple .txt that worked but not the admin/install and typing index.php no go. This what I get. 
--------
This page isn’t workinglocalhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500 or 
--------
This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Can you find the underlying error message for that 500 error in the Apache/nginx server logs in MAMP?

Comment: Change the PHP version to PHP 7.2.14